# Jquery select containers with same id's - IE 7 issue

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

"I have html that has 2 divs with the same id's in jquery i have it select the containers using $('#idname') in IE8/firefox/chrome it changes the html on both divs with that same id, but in ie 7 and below it only changes 1, how can i make this compatible with ie7 to select all divs with id? I would use classes but i already have a class that each of these div's share the same class name. Is there a div tag i can use for this other than id ?"

Ok i understand div's id should be unique, is there any other tag i can use other than title because it leave the tooltip mouseover on the div, that will allow me to select the value in jquery?

Thanks

Comment: Would the id name be an array now ? would i have to check for an array and go through it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I added custom html tags to the elements i needed to

```
<div customtag="infohere">
stuff here!
</div>
```

and used this jquery to select it

```
$('div[customtag='"+product+"']')
```

product being a variable with the id number of the element.

Comment: See @sarfraz answer, one unique ID per page. This answer is just an ugly-hack

Answer (score 2):

> I have html that has 2 divs with the
>   same id's in jquery i have it select
>   the containers using $('#idname') in
>   IE8/firefox/chrome it changes the html
>   on both divs with that same id

Ids can not be same, an `id` should be ***unique per element per page***. You need to use their common classes and modify your jquery code as per that or use some other surrounding elements to target your desired elements.

Comment: ok understood, so for instance say i have every product div with a class="product" and i use jquery to $('.product').each(function(){}); How would i then add another class and have jquery check the second class instead of product?

Comment: you can do $('.product.otherClass').each(function(){});

Comment: @Patricia: Exactly as far as we could understand it :)

Comment: Just a minor semantic quibble, but an `id` should be **unique per page**. (Unique per element per page sort of suggests that a `ul` and a `div` could both have an `id` of 'navigation' (for example).)

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple classes per element, but you can't have multiple elements with the same ID. Just put a space-separated list into the `class` attribute.

```
<div class="product foo"></div>
```

That div has two classes, "product" and "foo". Now your jQuery can do this...

```
$('.foo').each(...);
```

Or if you want to process only elements that have **both** "product" and "foo" classes, you can do this:

```
$('.product.foo').each(...);
```

If you want to do elements that have **either** "product" or "foo" classes...

```
$('.product, .foo').each(...);
```

Comment: Hey joel, gotcha on that ok say i wanted <div class="product product1"></div> <div class="product product1"></div>
<div class="product product2"></div> and so on how would i retrieve the product1 from the class using jquery?

Comment: Just do `$('.product1')` to select everything that has the "product1" class, regardless of what other classes might be on that element.

Comment: Ok heres my issue .product1 or .product2 is dynamic. so it may be .product454 on this load 234 on the next load

Comment: Perhaps your server-side code that generates `.product454` could also generate some client-side javascript that selects that class? You could make a JS function that takes the class name as a parameter, and then plugs it into `$('.' + theClassName)`